# i am calling ajax when button click event ng-click but ng-repeat does not load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

i was call ajax button click and ng-repeat does not load data one click but when i clicked two times its load, i don't know why please check code

```
 $scope.myData.doClick = function (item,event) {                             
                          var startdate = document.getElementById('txtstart').value;
                          var enddate = document.getElementById('txtend').value;
                          $.ajax({
                              type: "POST",
                              url: "studentattendance.aspx/GetEmployees",
                              data: JSON.stringify({ title: startdate, songname: enddate}),
                              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                              dataType: "json",
                              success: function (msg) {
                                  $scope.studentattendance = {};
                                      $scope.studentattendance = JSON.parse(msg.d);
                                  console.log($scope.studentattendance);

                              },
                              error: function (msg) {
                                  alert(msg.d);
                              }
                          });
                      }
```

//HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="info in studentattendance">
                                            <td>{{info.student_name}}</td>
                                            <td>{{info.father_name}}</td>
                                            <td>{{info.class_name}}</td>
                                            <td>{{info.attendancedate | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
                                            <td ng-if="info.attendanceType == 'Present'"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-circle"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></td>
                                             <td ng-if="info.attendanceType == 'Absent'"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></td>
                                             <td ng-if="info.attendanceType == 'Leave'"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-circle"><i class="fa fa-list"></i></td>


                                        </tr>
```

Click here

Comment: I think you have to define them separately.

Comment: use $http service from angular instead of $.ajax . Data is returning from $.ajax, but since that is part of jQuery, angular does not know about it and does not render again. When you click again, digest cycle is run, it detects new data and redraws it. Let me know if it's correct and I will post it as an answer. The other option would be using $scope.$apply() in your success callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.ajax` is part of `jQuery`, but not of `Angular`. So when it returns from your ajax request, angular context is not aware of your data changing. When you click again, a digest cycle is forced to run, and in that very moment new data is detected in your array - that's why you see it rendered again.

You have two options.

1- using `$scope.$apply()` in your success callback.

Like

```
success: function (msg) {
             $scope.studentattendance = {};
              $scope.studentattendance = JSON.parse(msg.d);
              console.log($scope.studentattendance);
             $scope.$apply();
}
```

2- using `$http` service from angular instead - it is a built in service which calls `$scope.$apply()` internally for you

Like

```
$http({
      method: "POST",
      url: "studentattendance.aspx/GetEmployees",
      dataType: 'json'
      data: JSON.stringify({ title: startdate, songname: enddate}),
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8" },
  }).then(function (msg) {
      $scope.studentattendance = {};
      $scope.studentattendance = JSON.parse(msg.d);
      console.log($scope.studentattendance);
      }, function (msg) {
     alert(msg.d);
  });
```

I would go for option two

Answer (score 0):

The real issue is that you're using jQuery's `ajax` instead of Angular's `$http`. When you don't do things like that through Angular, you're working outside of Angular's scope and it doesn't know about changes.

You can try:

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
  $scope.studentattendance = JSON.parse(msg.d);
});
```